# symfony petition without connect to database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm migrating a website to Symfony2. A part of this, similar to an API, is called by a desktop program many times per second to retrieve data from cache (APCu) or from database if don't exists. This only occurs one or two times per day.

For this, I want to skip database connection to avoid "too many connection" problems and manually connect if necessary. Now on flat php works fine but, can I do this on Symfony?

Thanks

Comment: cant you use cache on doctrine for this?

Comment: I want to avoid database connection, can doctrine cache do this??? I think that doctrine cache are the same solution that I'm using now, but I work directly with APCu

Comment: doctrine will also use a cache system like memcache/APC/file system which will create less connection to the database. But as you are using a cache you dont need that. How many concurrent connections you got active in db?

Comment: I have 500-750 connections from API+website on heavy load without cache (usually on weekends), and reduced to less than 100 with cache.
Doctrine only connect to database when execute a query without cache? If yes I don't have any problem, but I couldn't really check this in my test enviroment.

Comment: for caching doctrine depends on the settings you gave. See that configuration,also you can set multiple environments in doctrine which will effect caching.